# Numpy: np.finfo does not fail as one would expect

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I am using numpy.iinfo and np.finfo to test whether a given type or value is corresponds to an integer or a float. There is a weird behaviour when dealing with **None**.

The following fails, as expected:

```
 np.iinfo(None)
```

Nevertheless

```
 np.finfo(None)
```

does not, as I would expect. Is that a bug?
IMHO when type(None) returns NoneType, then np.finfo should fail as np.iinfo does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a purely technical level we can explain what you are seeing by looking at the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/9ae4f9bae9344ee0f1ca4d5767e49c196d534efc/numpy/core/getlimits.py)

The relevant snippet would be

```
@set_module('numpy')
class finfo(object):

<--snip-->   

    def __new__(cls, dtype):
        try:
            dtype = numeric.dtype(dtype)
        except TypeError:
            # In case a float instance was given
            dtype = numeric.dtype(type(dtype))
```

The behavior you see is a consequence of `np.dtype(None)` evaluating to `dtype('float64')`, which in itself doesn't feel 100% natural to me. Others (including devs) seem to [agree](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2190). For example

> Oh, well, we could probably deprecate dtype(None), which seems pretty
>   useless, but I don't know if it's worth the bother...

Based on this discussion and from the code above the way `None` is treated does indeed look a bit unintended, but that is just my educated guess.